# Integrating Flyway and Github

Tags: merge, version-control, source-control, git

I was wondering if any of you can share some experience regarding integrating Flyway and Git. We're currently developing a project, each sprint we need to make database changes for new features of course. Once every two weeks we merge changes made in dev DB to prod DB (the code reside on different branches in Git and we merge every two weeks). We want to start using Flyway for DB version control. Right now the idea is to create sql scripts on dev branch when we need a change, and run migrate on dev for every change we need. Then every two weeks when merge happens, the sql scripts will be merged to prod branch and then be run (using flyway migrate) using pipeline.
Does that sound like a good approach? Can anyone share some experience about it or suggest other approaches?

Comment: This question is pretty broad... It kind of feels like "teach me how to plug FlywayDb into my development process and pipeline" Which is a bit too broad for this site's format. I'd suggest narrowing focus to some **specific** areas you're having issues in, and start there.